# How can I change the name of my keyboard layouts on MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, language

I regularly switch between keyboards on a day-to-day basis, but I find it sort of irksome that on MacOS the Keyboards are listed in the menu all using their English names. On iOS, the keyboard names are displayed in the language they use, as in "日本語ローマ字" for Japanese, "한글" for Korean, or "简单拼音" for Chinese, and it makes it easy to identify when your brain is ready to start typing in a given language. But on MacOS, they display as things like "Hiragana," "2-Set Korean," and "Pinyin - Simplified" in a sea of other English named keyboards. How can I change this?